# Custom Catagory not found

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I created a custom post with a custom category like so

```
function fitters() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Fitters', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Fitter', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Fitters', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Fitters', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Fitter', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Fitter', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Fitter', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Fitter', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Fitters', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'fitter', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'fitter_categories', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-businessman',
    );
    register_post_type( 'fitter', $args );

}

function fitter_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'fitter_categories',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces).
        'fitter',            //post type name
        array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'label'             => 'Fitter States',  //Display name
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array(
                    'slug'          => 'fitter', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                    'with_front'    => false // Don't display the category base before
                    )
            )
        );
}
add_action( 'init', 'fitter_taxonomy');
```

When I try to view the archive for just that category I get a 404 error. Anyone know why?

So when I go to mysite.com/fitter it will list all the posts.
If I try to go to mysite.com/fitter/category-name I get a 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You can copy / paste archives.php and rename it archives-your_custom_post_slug.php this can help your thème to retrieve your custom tax.

Comment: I already have a archive-fitter.php file that works to pull all the posts. It just not finding the category if you try to sort them

Comment: Did you try to set 'with_front' to true ?